# What might cause a top-loading washing machine to leak once and then be fine for a few years and then leak again?

Tags: washing-machine

I have a rental unit where I'm not able to watch the machine to observe what is happening but:

About five years ago it leaked and water soaked through the ceiling below. After cleaning up the mess I could not observe any leaks after running it through many cycles. I put a pan under it and told the tenants to keep an eye on it. A few years later they moved out. When I went to the house after they moved, there was water in the tray. I cleaned it up, inspected, found nothing, and it was dry for a few years.

Now the tenant tells me there is water in the tray. I'm going to go drain it and inspect and probably find nothing again. Is it possible that some odd thing is happening that I won't be able to re-create? Should I just tell them to drain the pan and tell me if it fills up again?

FWIW these are good tenants and I trust them not to let it overflow.

Edit - I have the model number. Are there cheap parts that I should just replace as a safeguard?

http://www.searspartsdirect.com/model-number/nav3330eww/1268/0153200.html

Comment: sounds like the fill sensor is sticking every now and then,  or deposits in the valve allow the overfill. Are there strainers on the hot and cold water inlets?

Comment: I will need to check that the next time I am over there. I want to say yes, because I bought decent stainless braided hoses, but I can't know for sure.